# Trying to play video after splash screen in uwp

Tags: xaml, uwp

Hi I'm trying to play a video of 3sec after splash screen .But the issue is that not any video is playing for 3sec and then it redirect to "Home" screen.
Here is the code for that.Any help would be appreciated.
xaml

```
<Grid>
 <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" CurrentStateChanged="MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged"/>

    </Grid>
```

Cs code

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        internal Frame rootFrame;
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            myMediaElement.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Videos/splash_3.mp4");
            myMediaElement.AutoPlay = true;
 DissmissExtendedSplash();

        }
 private void MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (myMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Home));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MediaElement` has `CurrentStateChanged` Event which is what you are looking for. Move your Navigation even to this method and it should work for you as intended.

```
<Grid>
    <MediaElement x:Name="myMediaElement" CurrentStateChanged="MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

Below is how you need to check `MediaElement.CurrentState` to Navigate.

```
private void MediaElement_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myMediaElement.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Paused)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Home));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i' trying like this.check modified code but nothing happening not any video is playing.

Comment: if you want your video to play after splash screen you should try **myMediaElement.Play();** after splash screen and remove **myMediaElement.AutoPlay = true;**. Or try to play it with **AutoPlay** but on **Loaded** event. AVK Naidu answered correctly. See your code.